# How to orbit/zoom camera to decal/raycast?

Tags: three.js

I have [This Example](https://jsfiddle.net/roybarak/py6bo3jz/58/) (credit for @Mugen87) - as you can see the decals as being added to the Decals array, i’ve added a function that create list from the decals ( add decal and you will see it appear on the left top corner) - i wonder what’s the approach to point the camera to the exact location of the pointer when selecting one, so suppose i’ve added decal on the back of the head - and i want to get back to it without rotating manually - so i can click on it’s name - and get correct position.
I guess the way involves saving the intersections also and then set the camera position … something like this :

```
click on decal name function : 
//intersectionaArr - store intersections
camera.position.set(intersectionaArr[index of the decal].normal);
camera.lookAt(intersectionaArr[index of the decal].point);
camera.updateProjectionMatrix ();
```

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since you already have the position of the intersection point as well the orientation of the respective surface normal, you can do the following to compute the camera's position:

```js
const normal = new THREE.Vector3( 0, 0, 1 ).applyEuler( orientation );
const camPosition = new THREE.Vector3().copy( position ).add( normal.multiplyScalar( 50 ) );
```

So the idea is to compute a new camera position by starting from the intersection point and moving along the surface normal for a certain distance. It is 50 world units right now.

You can then store the camera position and intersection point in the list element and use it in your event listener to change the cameras position and orientation.

Updated fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/afsqm25t/2/